# ZFS pool import broken after upgrade

Tags: zfs

I lost my zfs pool while migrating from 12.04 to 14.04.

```
> sudo zpool status
pool: srv
state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing 
or invalid.  There are insufficient replicas for the pool to continue
functioning.
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
a backup source.
see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
scan: none requested
config:

NAME                                               STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
srv                                                UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
  raidz1-0                                         UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
    scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_HD103SJS246J9BZ600265-part1  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_HD501LJS0MUJ2MP805571-part1  UNAVAIL      0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_Maxtor_6H500F0_H80H5RYH-part1        UNAVAIL      0     0     0
> sudo zpool export srv
> sudo zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ srv -f
cannot import 'srv': I/O error
Destroy and re-create the pool from
a backup source.
> sudo zpool import -d /dev
pool: srv
 id: 8340478577715532614
 state: FAULTED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
 The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
 the '-f' flag.
 see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
config:

srv         FAULTED  corrupted data
  raidz1-0  ONLINE
    sdb1    ONLINE
    sdc     UNAVAIL  corrupted data
    sdd     UNAVAIL  corrupted data
```

I'm not sure what to do now. Is it possible to fix it somehow? Is it because it zpool is trying to use whole disks vs first partition?

Answer (score 1):

To import any type of ZFS pool to a system use:

```
sudo zfs import srv
```

it may fail which in that case you should use the -f option:

```
sudo zfs import -f srv
```

<sup>No need to tell ZFS the device name, just the pool name.</sup>

Pools are automatically discovered and imported if enough data is present on the disks.

I do not think you lost your data, it might be that the kernel module for ZFS needs to be updated.

I would recommend that you remove and install ZFS again from the ZFS on Linux repositories.